# input string to int from command line in java

Tags: java, string, int

I am writing a program in Java that makes use of the command line.

The program that I'm making is used by another program, **the problem is that my 4th parameter has to be an int**, for example 60(this is an int, it's used for calculations) for my program to work, and the program that uses it then has `fixedwidth:60`(this is a string) as the 4th parameter.

My question now is **how is it possible to still use the 60 in calculations** while not giving errors due to the program using it having a string as a 4th parameter and not an int. I have triend `Integer.parseInt` and `Integer.ToString`, but I still get the same error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post relevant code, Integer.parseInt should be what you're looking for

Comment: Please add relevant code, the command line you are invoking it with and the error you are getting.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't input the number alone instead of `fixedwidth:60`? @MichaelIT +1 for code, command line, and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on `:` and then parse the second part, like so -

```
String str = "fixedwidth:60";
String[] arr = str.split(":");
int val = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
// OR -
// int val = Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
System.out.println(val);
```

Output is

```
60
```

Comment: you can also use Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(String)` and `Integer.valueOf(String)` both expect the input `String` to be just the number you want to parse. That's why you probably get a `NumberFormatException` when trying to parse `"fixedwidth:60"`.

If you really need to input the whole string `"fixedwidth:60"`, you must first extract the number from that string. You can do that with Elliott Frisch's code using `String.split(":")`:

```
String str = "fixedwidth:60";
String[] arr = str.split(":"); // arr = { "fixedwidth", "60"}
int val = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]); // arr[1] = "60", which can be parsed
```